# NetBeans 8 extrimely slow opening large projects via Samba share

Tags: netbeans, virtualbox, netbeans-8, samba

I'm using Win 7 64bit as a host and Ubuntu 14.04 as a guest (Virtualbox).
All my projects are stored in the VM and I access them via Samba share. Both host and the guest systems are on SSDs, also manually copying files between those two does not have any performance issues.

I've been having problem with opening larger projects (like Laravel 5 ones) - it literally takes 10 minutes to open a single project. I've been mostly working on Wordpress projects recently and everything worked fine, but bigger projects are a real pain.

EDIT: I installed NetBeans 8.1 inside the VM and it's opening the same project in a flash.
Does anyone know on how to speed up this process?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Alloting RAM if you have sufficient enough for VM.

Comment: I increased the VM's RAM to 8GB (from 4GB) and this didn't solve the problem. My CPU (i7 4790K) supports virtualization (2 cores assigned to VM) so I don't think the issue is caused by my hardware/VM setup.

Answer (score 1):

Changing network adapter type of guest machine to Paravirtualized Network (virtio-net) solves problems like this.

[image: Network Adapter settings]